# AS2 Decryption issue BizTalk AS2

Tags: ssl, encryption, biztalk

I'm currently working on an AS/2 implementation (my first BizTalk project) and I'm facing an issue with certificates. I've checked numerous websites, blogs, MSDN and until now, I don't get it working.

Here's the scenario:
From a specific partner, I need to receive an AS/2 encrypted message.

Here's how I test this:
- I have my local computer and a server which both run BizTalk 2013.
- I have generated 1 certificate (DES3 2048 bits) by using OpenSSL.

The certificates are installed as follows:

Sending machine: Local Computer\Other People (My CER file).
Sending machine: Local Computer\Trusted Root Certification Authorities (My CER file) - To make the certificate trusted.
Receiving machine: Current User\Personal Store (My PFX file) - NOTE: Current user is the user under which the In-Process host instance of BizTalk is running.
Receiving machine: Current User\Personal Store (My PFX file) - to make the certificate trusted.  - NOTE: Current user is the user under which the In-Process host instance of BizTalk is running.

In IIS, the application pool running the BTSHttpReceive.dll is running under the ApplicationPoolIdentity.

And finally, here's the BizTalk configuration:

### (Sending parter):

- Send port -> Certificate: Receiving parner certificate (CER).
- Pary agreement (Sending partner -> Receing partner) -> Validation: "Message should be encrypted is selected" and the encryption algorithm is set to DES3.

  ### (Receiving partner):
- Host (BizTalkServerApplication) -> Certificates: My certificate (PFX).
- Party agreement (Sendingp partner -> Receing partner) -> Validation: "Message should be encrypted is selected" and encryption algorithm is set to DES3.

When I try to send a message from the sending computer to the receiving computer (just a text file with one line) the receiving computer generates two errors in BizTalk Event Viewer:

Error message 1:

The AS2 Decoder encountered an exception during processing.  Details of the message and exception are as follows:  AS2-From:"AS2-xxx" AS2-To:"AS2-xxx" MessageID:"" MessageType: "unknown" Exception:"An error occurred when decrypting an AS2 message."

Error message 2:

A message received by adapter "HTTP" on receive location "xxx" with URI "/BTSHttpReceive.dll" is suspended. 
 Error details: An output message of the component "Microsoft.BizTalk.EdiInt.PipelineComponents" in receive pipeline "Microsoft.BizTalk.EdiInt.DefaultPipelines.AS2Receive, Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.EdiIntPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" is suspended due to the following error: 
     An error occurred when decrypting an AS2 message..
 The sequence number of the suspended message is 2.
 MessageId:  {BFE72958-E968-4FF6-B7DA-EB31340D81F6}
 InstanceID: {B2B08761-4403-44AE-A788-D487F94CC270}

Here's what I have checked already:

Serial numbers or the certificate as I've seen that this might cause an issue:

Sending computer certificate serial number: ‎00 8a 42 09 ee af c2 29 b1
Receiving computer certificate serial number: ‎00 8a 42 09 ee af c2 29 b1

I hope someone can point me in the right direction because I'm searching for days on this issue.

Kind regards,

Comment: Which version of BizTalk are you using?

Comment: On the agreement between the parties in BizTalk on the incoming agreement tab under validation I've checked: "Use agreement settings for validation and MDN instead of message header." and "Message should be encrypted". My certificate for encryption / decryption has been stored in 2 location (other store or personal store depending on the function and then in the trusted root certificate authoroties because the certification is not trusted by default).

Comment: The question have been updated with some data that I know at this point. I hope that this sounds familiar for someone.

Comment: I'm using BizTalk 2013.

Comment: When dealing with AS2 issues, especially when having control over both sender and receiver, I often try to first make it work without any signing and encryption enabled. This way, I know for sure that this is not causing any issues.
Have you tried this already? Upon this, we can work out the issue further if necessary.

Comment: Also: From the question, I assume you're working with two BizTalk 2013 servers, sending to each other. Is this a correct assumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your response but I must say that I've managed to find the issue. It seems that the decrypting certificate should be registeren as the  BizTalk Isolated Host process user account.

Anyway, that solved my issue.